# Mixing sounds under windows

Tags: c, windows, winapi, playsound

Kinda disappointing, but using the `PlaySound` WinAPI function, it seems that it cannot play two sounds at the same time. Moreover I think it even delays it before you are able to play again. The reference seems to not mention this behavior and as far as I see it doesn't support channels.

---

What can I do in order to mix more than one sounds?

Comment: Take a look at [xaudio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415813(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: PlaySound is for basic sounds, such as alerts. It's not designed to be used in a multi-channel echo reverb amplified sampler mix music player. Try DirectSound for that.

Comment: @Jongware DirectSound ? And that is?

Comment: ... oh wait, my Windows-fu is a couple of years out of date. It seems nowadays it's called [WASAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370784(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Malina Why not use a search engine if you want to know what DirectSound is?

Comment: There's a new audio technology every other day with Windows :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What makes you think I did not? This is why I am asking. Because AFAIK (and as far as the research went) DirectSound is a driver.. not API. So I should hardcode everything in non-protected OS mode by virtue of BIOS interrupts or what?

Comment: Your search engine is broken

Comment: WASAPI is an even lower level API that provides direct access to hardware buffers.  XAudio is built on top of WASAPI.  DirectSound is an older API that was deprecated as of Windows 7.